# Tree View Explorer for Sharepoint online folder or Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-blob-storage

Greetings of the day. I hope everyone is safe and keeping up well.

I need some guidance and any help is highly appreciated.

**Current Scenario**
I have a tree view folder explorer GUI, when it opens, it shows a Tree View of a folder (the root folder is a Network share) and it's subfolder on Columns 1. User can expand and collapse it by clicking on +/- icons. When user select a folder, then it's contents, mainly files are showed in Column B, and user can tick them, and add them is Column 3 to download all of them on their laptop.

This all coding is written in C#.

[image]

**Problem**
Now the problem is, we wanted to move this Network folder to Azure Blob or Sharepoint,  but i can't any plugin, package or code, which can give me the same functionality.

Any thought and suggestion are welcome.

Regards
Aman

Comment: First decide on either Azure or Sharepoint. Those are two different things. For Azure have a look at the Microsoft.Azure.Storage nuget packages.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, for us, whatever is efficient and easy would work, Thanks , I will have a look